# What happens if you run out of fuel?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I'm wondering what happens if you run out of fuel between systems in ME3?

I think that in the second one, you just burnt your minerals, but having no minerals in ME3, what happens?

Also, I dont seem to find any refuel station... so how can I get fuel?

Comment: fyi there are refueling stations scattered at various locations in the galaxy

Comment: I usually visited the `Krogan DMZ` cluster, it has a refueling station in the very first solar-system.

Comment: Visiting the Citadel also refuels your ship for free, IIRC.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you run out of fuel, your ship is automatically forced into the system containing the Mass Relay and you will not be able to explore outside of it until you refuel.

Comment: Just like real life!